# Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationCurve' to different enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationTransition'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm getting some warnings when I use this line of code.

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut forView:nil cache:YES];
```

then i am getting some warning this is following

> Implicit conversion from enumeration type `UIViewAnimationCurve` to
>   different enumeration type `UIViewAnimationTransition`

So please suggest to me how to resolve this problem in iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut is not transition type for uiview animation transition, It's the type of animation curve. Following are the valid transition as per apple developer reference.

```
   UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown.
```

Please use one of them. If you want to set animation curve then do the following.

```
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
```

Comment: The default value for setAnimationCurve is UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut.

Comment: Just take a look at this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:

Comment: thanks, but sir i want animation of type UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut  in my custum view,   this method not work with custum view like as   [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut forView:viewAtLeft cache:YES];  any suggestion about this code.  i want this type of code line. any suggestion

Comment: [Go through this link](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=SlRMZUeu8oUC&pg=SA4-PA11&lpg=SA4-PA11&dq=UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut+forview&source=bl&ots=V-QJ08er2s&sig=uHm9arY5tz32iU2uKmB8l6K9uLo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QZqbT5W_E8qqrAer8Klh&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut%20forview&f=false)